# Making passed reference available to methods

Tags: c#, winforms, wizard

Currently I'm writing a wizard (using MBG SimpleWizard library). I have several pages. and as a way of sharing data between them, they are passed a class `out DBManip DBController`. I need to use this DBController in a method, but the call is handled by the library and so I can't easily pass DBController by reference to the method. How can I make the passed reference into a property that the method can modify, and preserve the reference.

Class Initialization:

```
    WizardHost host = new WizardHost();
    using (host)
    {
        host.Text = Migration.Properties.Resources.AppName;
        host.ShowFirstButton = false;
        host.ShowLastButton = false;
        host.WizardCompleted += new WizardHost.WizardCompletedEventHandler(this.Host_WizardCompleted);

        DBManip DBController;

        host.WizardPages.Add(1, new Page1());
        host.WizardPages.Add(2, new Page2(out DBController));
        host.WizardPages.Add(3, new Page3(out DBController));
        host.WizardPages.Add(4, new Page4(out DBController));
        host.LoadWizard();
        host.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Constructor:

```
 public Page2(out DBManip DBController)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.label1.Text = Migration.Properties.Resources.ExportDirectoryMessage;
            this.exportDirTextbox.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        }
```

Method:

```
private bool SetExportDirectory ()
{
    string exportDirectory = this.exportDirTextbox.Text;

    // If a path is given, check if it's valid
    // and set the pathExists boolean
    if (!Directory.Exists(exportDirectory))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Migration.Properties.Resources.InvalidPath);
        return false;
    }

    // Initializing the object to manipulate the databases
    exportDirectory = new DBManip(exportDirectory);
    return true;
}
```

Property which will call method:

```
public bool PageValid
{
    get { return SetExportDirectory(); }
}
```

Sorry if I'm missing something simple, I'm fairly new to C#

Comment: Are you saying that you want all of your Page classes (Page1, Page2, etc.) to share a reference to a common instance of `DBManip`, and you want `SetExportDirectory` to do something with that instance of `DBManip`? Which class is `SetExportDirectory` a member of?

Comment: To the first question, yes. To the second, it is a member of Page2, as is PageValid. (Page1 doesn't have a reference because it doesn't need one, but you get the idea).

Comment: I can only guess what you want to use `DBManip` for, but I've provided an answer showing how to a single instance of `DBManip` among the Page classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your pages are doing with DBManip, but you'll need to have it as a property of any Page class that uses it.

To do that, you'd ordinarily create an instance of DBManip first before creating the pages, and pass it to each constructor that wants it. Each of those classes will have a property where it stores the reference so it can use it later. *Each* class will need to declare that property for itself, since you're not easily going to be able to give them a common base class of your own.

But you're creating it later. Since you need the different classes to share a reference to an object that's created after their constructors exit, we'll add a quickie "reference" generic class, and they'll all share a reference to that. Then we can change its properties, and they'll all have the new property values on the existing instance of this little "handle" class.

Reference.cs

```
//  Semantically, this is basically a pointer to a pointer, without the asterisks.
public class Reference<T>
{
    public Reference() { }

    public Reference(T t) { Value = t; }

    public T Value;
}
```

Main C#

```
WizardHost host = new WizardHost();
using (host)
{
    host.Text = Migration.Properties.Resources.AppName;
    host.ShowFirstButton = false;
    host.ShowLastButton = false;
    host.WizardCompleted += new WizardHost.WizardCompletedEventHandler(this.Host_WizardCompleted);

    //  ************************
    //  Create shared "reference" instance
    //  ************************
    Reference<DBManip> dbControllerRef = new Reference<DBManip>();

    host.WizardPages.Add(1, new Page1());
    host.WizardPages.Add(2, new Page2(dbControllerRef));
    host.WizardPages.Add(3, new Page3(dbControllerRef));
    host.WizardPages.Add(4, new Page4(dbControllerRef));
    host.LoadWizard();
    host.ShowDialog();
}
```

Page2.cs

```
//  It's not an out parameter so don't make it one. 
public Page2(Reference<DBManip> dbControllerRef)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.DBControllerRef = dbControllerRef;

    this.label1.Text = 
        Migration.Properties.Resources.ExportDirectoryMessage;
    this.exportDirTextbox.Text = 
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}

public Reference<DBManip> DBControllerRef {
    get; private set;
}

private bool SetExportDirectory ()
{
    string exportDirectory = this.exportDirTextbox.Text;

    // If a path is given, check if it's valid
    // and set the pathExists boolean
    if (!Directory.Exists(exportDirectory))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Migration.Properties.Resources.InvalidPath);
        return false;
    }

    //  Everybody has the same Refernece<DBManip>
    this.DBControllerRef.Value = new DBManip(exportDirectory);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So to confirm, if I set one of DBController's parameters in page 2, that parameter will be accessible from page 3? Coming from C++, C# implicit reference stuff can be confusing.

Comment: As to what I am using the controller for, it does operations on the file system. It needs to store the directory provided on page 2, and then on page 3 it preforms operations based on the directory it was provided.

Comment: @AdrianSmith Right. Think of it as a pointer that's automagically dereferenced -- or think of it as a parameter `DBManip & DBController`, except unlike C++ references, it's rebindable to a different actual instance later on.

Comment: Okay, that actually makes some C# stuff in general make more sense.

Comment: Additional question, is there any way to no initialize dbController until inside of Page2. The constructor for dbManip relies on knowing the directory. If I have to I can rebuild that functionality, but I would prefer to deal with it on the front end.

Comment: @AdrianSmith Ohh, that's why you had the out parameters. Now I get it. I'd write a simple class that just has a reference to DBManip -- I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @AdrianSmith Rewrote my answer. It's all making a lot more sense now. I don't know of a direct, out-of-the-box way to do that in C# (there's the WeakReference class, which is at least very close), but it's very quick to whip up something to do the job. Next time around, you'd just write DBManip differently, so the same instance could exist from the get-go.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have a tendency to lean to heavily on my constructors.